# Can not set the value of Flet dropdown

Tags: python, dropdown, flet

Can not set the value of the dropdown. I'm using an example from the `flet` site.
The only way of set the value is add some item do the dropdown but
But what i need is set the value without any selection item?
Thank you!

```py
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    def find_option(option_name):
        for option in d.options:
            if option_name == option.key:
                return option
            return None

    def add_clicked(e):
        d.value = "test"
        page.update()
    
    def delete_clicked(e):
        option = find_option(d.value)
        if option != None:
            d.options.remove(option)
            # d.value = None
            page.update()

d = ft.Dropdown()
option_textbox = ft.TextField(hint_text="Enter item name")
add = ft.ElevatedButton("Add", on_click=add_clicked)
delete = ft.OutlinedButton("Delete selected", on_click=delete_clicked)
page.padding = 50
page.add(d, ft.Row(controls=[option_textbox, add, delete]))

ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: I am not sure of your situation right now. It may help to explain in detail whether you are getting errors, whether you are running the flet in a jupyter environment and getting errors, what version of flet you are currently using, etc., which may help to resolve the issue. I have run the example in the reference in my environment and it runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

flet.Dropdown need flet.dropdown.Option in the 'options' list with the same value you want set.

the example is here:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    def find_option(option_name):
        for option in d.options:
            if option_name == option.key:
                return option
            return None

    def add_clicked(e):
        d.value = "test"
        page.update()
    
    def delete_clicked(e):
        option = find_option(d.value)
        if option != None:
            d.options.remove(option)
            # d.value = None
            page.update()

    d = ft.Dropdown(options=[ft.dropdown.Option("test")]) # simple change
    option_textbox = ft.TextField(hint_text="Enter item name")
    add = ft.ElevatedButton("Add", on_click=add_clicked)
    delete = ft.OutlinedButton("Delete selected", on_click=delete_clicked)
    page.padding = 50
    page.add(d, ft.Row(controls=[option_textbox, add, delete]))

ft.app(target=main)
```